# Why can't I buy the Hjerim house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Every time I talk to jorleif about buying hjerim, there is no dialogue options menu or anything. I have completed the stormcloaks storyline and blood on the ice but nothing. I didn't get a quest to become thane but I don't know if that's a thing or not. I've spent hours trying to fix this but I am unable to get this resolved.

Comment: Why did you roll back @ZeroStack's changes? They greatly improved the post.

Comment: I did? sry 1 sec

Comment: I still cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for a few hours (in-game), exiting and restarting the game (waiting for real minutes before restarting helps),  or reload saves.

Comment: ive retried reloading saves b4 and completed both questlines twice. ive yet to try the whole wait, exit, restart, wait irl.

Comment: nope. didn't work

Comment: Yeah, you have to become Thane.

Comment: I never get the quest to. ulfric mentioned it but nope. ivealready helped 5 citizens seeing if that would do something. jorleif wont even speak to me.